# How to Handle ValueError from Dataframe use Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am developing Spark using Scala, and I don't have any background of Scala. I don't get the ValueError Yet, but I am preparing the ValueError Handler for my code.

```
|location|arrDate|deptDate|
|JFK     |1201   |1209    |
|LAX     |1208   |1212    |
|NYC     |       |1209    |
|22      |1201   |1209    |
|SFO     |1202   |1209    |
```

If we have data like this, I would like to store Third row and Fourth row into Error.dat then process the fifth row again. In the error log, I would like to put the information of the data such as which file, the number of the row, and details of error. For logger, I am using log4j now.

What is the best way to implement that function? Can you guys help me?

Comment: on what conditions 3'rd and 4'th row are rejected to error files?

Comment: @rogue-one from 3'rd arrDate is empty, and the 4'th row location data should be String. These are the condition of rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming all the three columns are type String. in that case I would solve this using the below snippet. I have created two udf to check for the error records.

- if a field is has only numeric characters [`isNumber`]
- and if the string field is empty [`isEmpty`]

code snippet

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
 import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

 val df = rdd.zipWithIndex.map({case ((x,y,z),index) => (index+1,x,y,z)}).toDF("row_num", "c1", "c2", "c3")
 val isNumber = udf((x: String) => x.replaceAll("\\d","") == "")
 val isEmpty = udf((x: String) => x.trim.length==0)
 val errDF = df.filter(isNumber($"c1") || isEmpty($"c2"))
 val validDF = df.filter(!(isNumber($"c1") || isEmpty($"c2")))


scala> df.show()
+-------+---+-----+-----+
|row_num| c1|   c2|   c3|
+-------+---+-----+-----+
|      1|JFK| 1201| 1209|
|      2|LAX| 1208| 1212|
|      3|NYC|     | 1209|
|      4| 22| 1201| 1209|
|      5|SFO| 1202| 1209|
+-------+---+-----+-----+

scala> errDF.show()
+-------+---+----+----+
|row_num| c1|  c2|  c3|
+-------+---+----+----+
|      3|NYC|    |1209|
|      4| 22|1201|1209|
+-------+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant suggestion. Another question is what if I want to check all columns if there is any empty columns?

Comment: This is what I did to check all columns.

Comment: @BryanK. I missed your comment. you can apply the same udf to all columns to check for blank string

Comment: val columnNames = Seq("row_num","c1","c2","c3")
var errDF = df.filter(isEmpty(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)), but it did not work. Is there any way to check multiple columns in once?

Comment: I created the sequence because I have 46 columns, and I don't want to run it 46 times.